# Perturbation of eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, perturbation-theory

I came across [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_perturbation#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20an%20eigenvalue%20perturbation,to%20changes%20in%20the%20system.) giving approximate formulas for eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a perturbed matrix. Namely,

Let $A' \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a real symmetric positive definite matrix with distinct eigenvalues $\{t_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and their corresponding orthonormal eigenvectors $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$. Assume that $t_1 > t_2 > \cdots > t_n$. Let $E \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ a real symmetric matrix. Consider a perturbation $A$ of $A'$ given by $A=A'+E$, with the eigenpairs of $A$ denoted by $\{(s_i,w_i)\}_{i=1}^n$. The approximated eigenvectors of $A$ are given by

$$ \widetilde{w}_{i} = v_{i} + \sum_{k=1, k \neq i}^{n} \frac{(Ev_i,v_k)}{t_i-t_k}v_k + O(\|E\|_2^2), \quad 1 \leq i \leq n , $$

and the approximated eigenvalues of $A$ are given by

$$\widetilde{s}_i = t_i + v_i^TEv_i + O(\|E\|_2^2), \quad 1 \leq i \leq n $$

My question is if there exists similar formula for the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of a linear *operator*? i.e., to linear operators in an infinite dimensional linear space.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Frechet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) and/or [Gateux derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative)?  (I ask because the equations you recite are the first-order Taylor series, which takes us straight to [functional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative).)

Comment: @EricTowers, Not in particular, but I can read about it if the answer depends on it

Answer (score 0):

See the canonical reference:

*Kato, Tosio*, Perturbation theory for linear operators., Classics in Mathematics. Berlin: Springer-Verlag. xxi, 619 p. (1995). [ZBL0836.47009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0836.47009).

Also see:

*Albeverio, Sergio; Kuzhel, Sergei; Nizhnik, Leonid P.*, [**On the perturbation theory of self-adjoint operators**](http://dx.doi.org/10.3836/tjm/1233844052), Tokyo J. Math. 31, No. 2, 273-292 (2008). [ZBL1182.47013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1182.47013).

Comment: Thanks. I actually found this reference myself but couldn't find expressions of the same form... or have I missed / didn't recognize it?

Comment: @catch22 A lot of the theory is devoted to sorting out the various kinds of operators you are perturbing, and the various kinds of perturbations, but when the smoke clears, the theory is pretty similar to the finite-dimensional case.